# Why is a matched substring returning "undefined" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, firebug

I came across a strange behaviour when doing some regular expressions in JavaScript today (Firefox 3 on Windows Vista).

```
var str = "format_%A";
var format = /(?:^|\s)format_(.*?)(?:\s|$)/.exec(str);

console.log(format);    // ["format_%A", "%A"]
console.log(format[0]); // "format_undefined"
console.log(format[1]); // Undefined
```

There's nothing wrong with the regular expression. As you can see, it has matched the correct part in the first `console.log` call.

Internet Explorer 7 and Chrome both behave as expected: `format[1]` returns "%A" *(well, Internet Explorer 7 doing something right was a bit unexpected...)*

Is this a bug in Firefox, or some "feature" I don't know about?

Comment: I've never seen the literal matching syntax you're using here. Can you point at some web resource where one can read about it?

Comment: I think at least a link to the previous almost-the-same question should be provided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex

Comment: @PEZ: what literal matching syntax are you talking about?

Comment: @PEZ: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: This is not a firefox issue, it's a firebug issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because console.log() works like printf(). The first argument to console.log() is actually a format string which may be followed with additional arguments. %A is a placeholder. For example:

```
console.log("My name is %A", "John"); // My name is "John"
```

See [console.log() documentation](http://getfirebug.com/console.html) for details. %A and any other undocumented placeholders seem to do the same as %o.

Comment: To be clear, this is not how console.log behaves in Safari's Web Inspector.

Comment: Firefox does not behave like this - this is apparently a firebug specific feature.  Has this ever been anything other than a firebug feature?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `%A` somehow translates into the string `undefined`.

Try escaping the `%A` part, I think that will solve the problem.

Comment: Good catch. It's treated as a URL escape (like %20 and the like) but then %A isn't one of those so gets to be undefined.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with Firebug